# IndexOutOfBoundsException when debugging foreach statement

Tags: c#, sql, list, foreach, indexoutofboundsexception

//I've list out the codes below, pls take a look and i'd appreciate if i can get some help. My program which is throwing index out of bound exception at line String studadmin = admin[g];

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //retrieve studentdetails using List<String[];

    List<String[]> stud = new List<String[]>();         
    int i = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (check.Checked)
        {
            String [] studDetail = new String [1];
            studDetail[0] = row.Cells[1].Text;
            stud.Add(studDetail);
        }
        i++;

    }
    int g = 0;
    foreach (String[] admin in stud)
    {
        String studadmin = admin[g]; 
        // here's whr the error are prompted (IndexOutOfBoundsException),
        // when it reads the following "admin", the loop just ends here with an error;         

            try
            {
                myConnection = db.getConnection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_IPPLOAssign");
                cmd.Connection = myConnection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcadYear", lb_AcadYear.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcadPeriod", lb_AcadPeriod.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPPProjID", lb_ProjID.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjSubID", "0");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOLoginID", ddl_LO.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", Session["UserID"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adminno", studadmin);

                myConnection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                lb_Msg.Text = "Update Success.";
                lb_error.Text = "";


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                share.WriteLog(ex.Message, "LOAssign.aspx", "Button1_Click()", "Error in updating LO.");

                lb_error.Text = "Update failed.";
                lb_Msg.Text = "";
            }
            finally
            {
                if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    myConnection.Close();
            }

        g++; //loop the subsequent studadmin and store into database
    }



    refresh_gvCompany();
    refresh_gvCurrent();  //refresh gridview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed your parameter names are exactly correct? Should @Adminno be @AdminNo, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Every item in your `stud` is **an array of `String` of size 1**.

However, at every iteration you are increasing the index of array:

```
String studadmin = admin[g];
// ...
g++; // loop the subsequent studadmin and store into database
```

As the result, you actually try to access `stud[0][0]`, `stud[1][1]`... the errors occurs here, because `stud[1]` contains only one item.

You need to remove `i` and `g` - they are both useless.

As your array only contains one item, it actually looks like you misunderstand usage of `List` and array. Probably, you want a `List<string>` instead of `List<string[]>`:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    List<string> stud = new List<string>();         

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (check.Checked)
        {
            stud.Add(row.Cells[1].Text);
        }    
    }

    foreach (string studadmin in stud)
    {
        try
        {
            myConnection = db.getConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_IPPLOAssign");
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcadYear", lb_AcadYear.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcadPeriod", lb_AcadPeriod.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPPProjID", lb_ProjID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjSubID", "0");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOLoginID", ddl_LO.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", Session["UserID"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adminno", studadmin);

            myConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            lb_Msg.Text = "Update Success.";
            lb_error.Text = "";       
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            share.WriteLog(ex.Message, "LOAssign.aspx", "Button1_Click()", "Error in updating LO.");

            lb_error.Text = "Update failed.";
            lb_Msg.Text = "";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                myConnection.Close();
            }
    }

    refresh_gvCompany();
    refresh_gvCurrent(); 
}
```